# If a circle, whose radius squared is an integer, has rational points on its circumference, then at least one of those points is a lattice point.

Tags: number-theory, circles, integer-lattices

More specifically, if $x^2 + y^2 = N$, where N is an integer, has rational solutions, then at least one of them is an integer solution. How do you go about proving this?

Comment: What have you tried already?  You're more likely to get better answers when people understand what you've already thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's well-known which positive integers are the sum of two squares, namely
those where each prime $\equiv3\pmod 4$ occur to an even power in its prime factorisation. Let $A$ be the set of these numbers. Your result follows
from the observation that if $n^2a\in A$ where $n$ and $a$ are integers,
then $a\in A$. This comes from this characterisation of the elements of $A$.